# Flask render_template() does not send context parameters in requests

Tags: flask

I am working on an app, and I want to send some parameters to render a page properly.

Here is my Flask code:

```
@app.get('/main')
def interface():
    if True:  # here supposed to be a function to check authorization
        s = 'HELLO'  # for testing purposes I hardcode the dummy parameter
        return render_template('main.html', sid=s)
    return redirect('/')  # if not authorized, move home
```

When I run the app and try to open 127.0.0.1:5000/main , the parameter is not passed.
I can see it in the developer console:

[image]

However if I write the address manually, like 127.0.0.1:5000/main?sid=HELLO, I see this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `render_template('main.html', sid=s)` means Flask will respond to the the `/main` path with the contents from the main.html template, and to generate that template the sid=HELLO will be used.

If you want Flask to redirect to a different path with a GET variable in the path, you would have to use `url_for`, example:

```
return redirect(url_for("user.logout", user="admin")
```

See these two routes that may explain:

```
@main_blueprint.route("/login")
def login():
    # lets assume your login processing determines the credentials submitted are for admin:
    user = "admin"
    return redirect(url_for("main_blueprint.user", id=user))

@main_blueprint.route("/user/<id>")
def user(id):
    return "welcome user: {}".format(id)
```

by doing a GET to `/login`, you will be redirected to `/user/admin`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, using redirect + url_for is better indeed.